# Finding match in column values and summing up the values

Tags: excel

Anybody know how to match a cell contents in a columns and sum up the values using excel formula bar only.

[image: sample]

The formula will match up to the given date. If `May 16` is the date provided, then the formula will just look for the matching date in the column. If the date given match up with the date in the column, then, it will sum up the values in column `AA` and `BB` until only the cell with the same date. I'm just trying to figure this out not using vba.

I'm unfortunate enough to find for any solutions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following formula:

```
=SUMIF($BC$5:$BC$15,$BD$1,$AA$5:$AA$15)

=SUMIF($BC$5:$BC$15,$BD$1,$BB$5:$BB$15)
```

or

If `AA`, `BB` and `Date` are column names then you can use the following formula:

```
=SUMIF(Date,D1,AA)

=SUMIF(Date,D1,BB)
```

See the image below:

[image]

Comment: @ramedhu - I've edited the answer though it seems like you have already written the formula.

Comment: Thank you for the edit! It's all working well now. Thanks for saving me! :)